# Perl - get free disk space usage on linux

Tags: linux, perl, awk

I'm wondering how I can get the value of the second row, 4th column from df ("/"). Here's the output from df:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs          208G  120G   78G  61% /
fakefs          208G  120G   78G  61% /root
fakefs          1.8T  1.3T  552G  70% /home4/user
fakefs          4.0G  1.3G  2.8G  31% /ramdisk/bin
fakefs          4.0G  1.3G  2.8G  31% /ramdisk/etc
fakefs          4.0G  1.3G  2.8G  31% /ramdisk/php
fakefs          208G  120G   78G  61% /var/lib
fakefs          208G  120G   78G  61% /var/lib/mysql
fakefs          208G  120G   78G  61% /var/log
fakefs          208G  120G   78G  61% /var/spool
fakefs          208G  120G   78G  61% /var/run
fakefs          4.0G  361M  3.7G   9% /var/tmp
fakefs          208G  120G   78G  61% /var/cache/man
```

I'm trying to get the available free space (78GB) using perl which I'm fairly new to. I'm able to get the value using the following linux command but I've heard it's not necessary to use awk in perl at all because perl can do what awk can natively.

```
df -h | tail -n +2 | sed -n '2p' | awk '{ print $4 }'
```

I'm stumped. I tried using the Filesys::df module but when I'd print out the available usage percent, it'd give me a different value than what running df from command line does. Help is appreciated.

Comment: `awk 'NR==2{ print $4 }'`

Comment: For me the above command working fine.

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to do `df /root` to get just one record that you need?

Comment: What code are you using with `Filesys::Df`, and what is it returning?

Comment: @duskwuff I managed to figure it out and it was a simple mistake on my part. I wasn't specifying the correct block size required to give the results I was expecting. I think we're all good here.

Comment: Have a look at http://search.cpan.org/~iguthrie/Filesys-DfPortable-0.85/DfPortable.pm for a more natural Perl way of doing this.

Comment: Thank you for that link. I did end up using filesys::df for this~

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A little more succinctly:

```
df -h | perl -wlane 'print $F[3] if $. == 2;'


-w   enable warnings
-l   add newline to output(and chomps newline from input line)
-a   splits the fields on whitespace into the @F array, which you access using the syntax $F[n] (first column is at index position 0)
-n   puts the code inside the following loop:

    LINE:
        while (<>) { 
            ...     # code goes here
        }
     # <> reads lines from STDIN if no filenames are given on the command line

-e   execute the string
$.   current line number in the file (For the first line, $. is 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to do this all in `perl`, then:

```
df -h | perl -e 'while (<stdin>) { if ($. == 2) { @x = split; print $x[3] }}'
```

This uses `perl` alone to read the output of `df -h` and, for the second record (`$. == 2`) splits the record into fields, based on whitespace, and outputs field 3 (counting from 0).

Comment: Thanks for your response. That works like a charm. I managed to get Filesys::df working but I will certainly keep tabs on this just incase I need to use it in the future for whatever reason!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work ok too:

```
df -h | awk 'NR==2 {print $4}'
```

Get the second line and pint fourth field.